# what does routingKey & exchange actually does in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

is the routing key only used to route the message for a particular exchange to a specific queue?

aRe there some object created when we are mentioning following command:

-> channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange:"demo_exchange",type:"direct");
-> channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "demo_exchange",
                                 routingKey: "hello",
                                 basicProperties: null,
                                 body: body);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this tutorial:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html

> We will use a direct exchange instead. The routing algorithm behind a
>   direct exchange is simple - a message goes to the queues whose binding
>   key exactly matches the routing key of the message.

:

"aRe there some object created when we are mentioning following command:"
which object? What do you mean?

Comment: actually i can see the list of exchnages and queues being created but can i see the routing values or are they just used as some sort of variable for routing?